# Question about the application of the Mean value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**Question:**
Let $f$ be a real-valued differentiable function in $(a, b)$. Suppose that there exist $x, y ∈ (a, b)$ such
that $x < y$, $f'(x) = 0 = f'(y)$ and $(f(y)−f(x))/
(y−x) > 0$. Prove that there exist a $ζ ∈ (x, y)$ such that
$(f(ζ) − f(x))/(ζ − x)
= f'(ζ)$

**My Approach:**
I thought this is an easy question because the condition says that $f$ is differentiable, which means it is continuous. So it satisfies the condition for applying the mean value Theorem. Since $(x,y) ∈ (a,b)$, the differentiability and continuity still holds for domain $(x,y)$ which means we can still apply the mean value theorem, and thus proving the statement true.

However, according to this approach, I am not fully using the conditions giving in the question: $x < y$, $f'(x) = 0 = f'(y)$ and $(f(y)−f(x))/
(y−x )> 0$

Am I missing something about proving this statement?

Comment: Doesn't the MVT only tell you that there is some $c \in (x,y)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}$? The demand on $\zeta$ is quite different from this.

Comment: But isn't it same for ζ when $(x,y)$ shares the same characteristic as $(a,b)$? f is still continuous and differentiable in the (x,y) range, which makes the MVT applicable. Or am I missing some part about the symbol ζ itself?

Comment: The same $\zeta$ is appearing in both the derivative and the ratio, while in the MVT the derivative is of some different point while the ratio has $f(y)$ and $y$. Basically $f'(c) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}$ is different from $f'(c) = \frac{f(\mathbf{c}) - f(x)}{\mathbf{c} - x}$ (bold for emphasis).

Comment: Could you give some hint about how to apply the given conditions that I didn't use for proving the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let
$$
\phi(\xi)=\cases{0&if $\ \xi=x$\\
                 \displaystyle\frac{f(\xi)-f(x)}{\xi-x}&if $\ \xi\in(a,x)\cup(x,b)\ $.}
$$

- Can you show that $\ \phi\ $ is continuous on the interval $\ [x,b)\ $ and differentiable in its interior?
- Can you show that $\ \phi\ $ must attain its supremum inside the interval $\ (x,y)\ $? (Hint: What is the sign of $\ \phi'(y)\ $?)
- If $\ \zeta\ $ is the supremum of $\ \phi\ $ in the interval $\ (x,y)\ $, what do you get when you plug $\ \zeta\ $ into the equation $\ \phi'(\zeta)=0\ $.